# Meteor / Javascript function error - TypeError: callback is not a function

Tags: javascript, meteor

I've been looking at other Stack Overflow questions and I still can't figure mine out. I'm getting this error in the browser console:

```
Exception in delivering result of invoking 'formMethod1': TypeError: callback is not a function
```

I've put my code below and a comment on the line the error references. It seems that the "err" object isn't getting passed, but the callback is actually being called and the whole thing goes through, it just never catches the error.

```js
submitForm1(entry,
 processForm1(err,res,entry,function(err,res){
  //Done processing
  console.log(err); //Doesn't work
  console.log(res); //Doesn't work
  console.log("Done"); //Works
    })
)   

function submitForm1(entry, callback) {

    Meteor.call('formMethod1', {
            params: {
                user: Meteor.user().username,
                activity: entry
            }
        }, function(err,res){
            if(err){
             console.log(err) //Works
                callback(err, res, entry) //This is where the error happens
            } else{
                callback(undefined, res, entry)
            }
        }
    );
}

function processForm1(err, res, entry, callback) {
 console.log(err); //Doesn't work
 console.log(res); //Works
 console.log(entry); //Works
    if (err) {
        if (err.error == "1001") { //Activity not found
            //Handle Error
            callback("Activity Not Found");
        } else {
            //Handle Error
            callback(err.message);
        }
    } else { //No Errors
        callback(undefined,"Submitted");
    }
}
```

EDIT: You all got me going in the right direction. Here's the corrected code:

```js
submitForm1(entry, function(err,res){
    processForm1(err,res,entry,function(err,res){
        //Done processing
  console.log(err); 
  console.log(res); 
  console.log("Done");
    })
});
```

Comment: processForm1 doesn't return a function. If you want to call it and use it's result as a callback, you need it to return a function.

Comment: you are using two level callbacks when you call submitForm1, is that something you want since it makes the logic a bit complex?

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the function you pass as callback, instead of ... passing it, but then pass another function as argument to *that*. I think you mixed up two flavours of the same function together in a wrong mix. Fix like this:

```
submitForm1(entry,
    function (err,res,entry) {
        //Done processing
        console.log(err);
        console.log(res);
        console.log("Done");
    }
)
```

Comment: Thank you! This got me in going in the right direction. Turns out I was also inheriting a 'res' object which didn't help with the troubleshooting. I'll update my question with the fixed code.

Comment: Note that in your edit to your question, the third argument passed to the callback call is going nowhere.

Comment: Thank you. I missed that, too.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `processForm1` as a callback to `submitForm1`. If you do this you have to make sure that the signature which is called inside `processForm1` matches `(err, res, entry, callback)`.

This means that you need to pass a method as callback inside `submitForm1` which gets called inside it. Makes sense?

For simplicity let's put it this way:

```
     function submitForm1(entry, function(err,res,entry,function(err,res){
           //Done processing
           console.log(err); //Doesn't work
           console.log(res); //Doesn't work
           console.log("Done"); //Works
     }) {

     Meteor.call('formMethod1', {
             params: {
                 user: Meteor.user().username,
                 activity: entry
             }
         }, function(err,res){
             if(err){
               console.log(err) //Works
                 callback(err, res, entry) //This is where the error happens
             } else{
                 callback(undefined, res, entry)
             }
         }
     );
 }
```

No you see what's wrong.